# Which is the best way to print html with php?

Tags: php, html

I need to print info from a database to a html template, but i've read that there are best practices rather than just printing the html required. Kinda a template filler.

Thanks.

Edit: i found the framework [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net), so, from an html template with variable fields, I can fill the fields like this `$smarty->assign('htmlVar', $data);` and then load it.

Thanks, again.

Comment: Since it is large, it would be more readable if you just type the elements rather that echoing them.

Comment: template engine.

Comment: @rtfm If would be nice if you explain how a "template engine" can help OP

Comment: @Swellar I cannot type them because the objects are constantly being posted and deleted from the database.

Comment: considering how poorly the question is asked, OP is lucky to get that much

Comment: Actually,  you can type them, you just need the proper conditions so that not all will be rendered. It's like you are saying that " I cannot **echo** them because the objects are constantly being posted and deleted from the database."

Comment: @rtfm I'm developing a webpage where the users can see the products that other ones are selling, but since I have to print sort of things like, in one section of the html  have to print the categories of the products, in another section the most searched products with their respective information, in other section (of another page) the full details of the product selected and so. Do I explain?

Answer (score 2):

## A couple of alternative methods (of many)

We can use [DOMDocument::createElement](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php) and many related methods to build a DOM which can then be output.

> This function creates a new instance of class DOMElement. This node will not show up in the document unless it is inserted with (e.g.) `DOMNode::appendChild()`.

[Another alternative](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) to echoing strings of HTML, is to use something like:

```
<?php if ( condition ): ?>
<p>This will be output</p>
<?php elseif ( other_condition ): ?>
<p>This will be output instead</p>
<?php else: ?>
<p>Or this</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```